# How to enable/disable toolbar scrolling programmatically when using design support library

Tags: android, toolbar, android-support-design

I use support design library to show/hide toolbar when scrolling a recyclerView inside a fragment, as mention here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It works grate, Now I want to enable/disable toolbar scrolling programmatically because I use fragments and I need to stop this feature for some fragments.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `Toolbar`, being a child of the `AppBarLayout`, gets its `LayoutParams` from the `AppBarLayout`.  These layout params have the scroll flags that are set in the XML.

So, you get the `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams` from the `Toolbar`, and call
`setScrollFlags()` to change the flags to the value you want.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  // or however you need to do it for your code
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_NO_SCROLL);  // clear all scroll flags
```

Comment: And to add the scrolling back at runtime, use the same method with the constants [from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS)

Comment: I want the same behavior. It worked but the problem I'm having is that, when I set the flags to 0, the nestedScrollView's height is reduced and it creates a huge blank space at the bottom of the content. Please help if someone knows about it.

Comment: @VineetAshtekar You could try taking the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior off the `NestedScrollView` at the same time.  Since the toolbar can no longer scroll, there's no reason to lay out the `NestedScrollView` as if it can.  I don't know exactly how to do that programmatically; I am looking into it.

Comment: I'm using the same lines of code to change the scroll flags of my CollapsingToolbarLayout. But I need to trigger this code when AppBarLayout is touched by the user. However, my issue is that the changing scroll flags would be effective until I release the touch. Any ideas to change the scroll flags immediately while the user still touching the AppBarLayout?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to fix the above issue by programmatically adding fake ACTION_CANCEL and ACTION_DOWN events after changing scroll flags.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me when I'm using a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: After support 25.3.1, it need to invoke `appBarLayout.requestLayout()` to take effects.

Answer (score 12):

Remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` wherever you want to disable taskbar scrolling.

Comment: I would like to do it programmatically

Comment: You can set it like this if you want it disabled in xml:

     app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed"